# Evalute passed in variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting

Is there a way to pass in a variable as an argument to a bash script and have it evaluated scoped by the bash script?

**Given**:

```
# cat /path/to/file/of/host/names
bob
tom
joe
etc...


# dofor
FILE=$1
shift
CMD=$*

while read host; do
    # recursively turns "ssh \$host hostname" from $@ into:
    # ssh bob hostname
    # ssh tom hostname
    # ssh joe hostname
    # etc...
    eval $CMD
done < $FILE
```

**When**:

```
# dofor /path/to/file/of/host/names "ssh \$host hostname"
```

**Then**: I'd receive the output from running `ssh host hostname` for each hostname listed in /path/to/file/of/host/names. e.g.:

```
bob.example.com
tom.example.com
joe.example.com
etc...
```

Comment: I cannot figure out what's the question here: the `dofor` code as posted already does what you're asking...

Comment: @RiccardoMurri It does as long as, in invocation, the second parameter passed to the script (one that contains `$host` is enclosed in single quotes *and* the command does not try to steal access to stdin.

Comment: Indeed, I suppose I was just unnecessarily escaping the $host. Sorry for that, I was certain I'd checked that that wasn't the reason it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
exec 3<$FILE
while read -u 3 host; do
    $2 $host $3
done
```

Then if you have:

```
$ cat /tmp/hostnames
some.host1.com
another.host2.net
some.host3.org    
some.host4.com
```

and run `dofor.sh /tmp/hostnames ssh ls`, it will run in sequence:

```
ssh some.host1.com ls
ssh another.host2.net ls
ssh some.host3.org ls
ssh some.host4.com ls
```

**EDIT1:**

If you'd like to change `ssh` or `ls` into some longer commands (or parts of such), just use quotes:

```
dofor.sh /tmp/hostnames "ssh -p 23" "ls -lh /"
```

---

**EDIT2:**

With the following script, you'll be able to use `$host` variable in as many places in your command as you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<$1
while read -u 3 host; do
    eval $2
done
```

(I made this one shorter - no useless introducing of `$FILE` variable.)
The important part here is that you need to use **single quotes** around the command containing the $host variable:

```
 dofor.sh /tmp/hostnames 'echo "trying $host :"; ssh -p 23 myuser@$host "ls -lh /"'
```

But *beware* that it is dangerous to use `eval` (see [l0b0's wall](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3645/l0b0)) because if the file `/tmp/hostnames` contained a command on some line, it would be executed. ***Better not use this as `root`!***

Comment: that's an alternate method sure, granted there's no way to ensure that the $2'th and $3'th arguments will always surround the argument that I've passed in, and want replaced by values from the file

Comment: So you mean to say you want to be able to use $host in different places in the command? But just once in each?

Comment: not necessarily. I want the $argument, possibly multiple times, that I pass to the script to be evaluated in the context of the for loop

Comment: I see. If that's te main point, I'll think about it... Meanwhile, I corrected the script to allow commands like `ssh` to steal your input without breaking the while-read-loop. (The previous version would exit after executing `ssh` if it prompted for password.)

Comment: See the last edit - no need to use any substitution if you use single quotes.

Comment: I had considered that it was how I escaped the variable, however, it doesn't seem to work still. This is what I get: `# dofor ~/tmp/hosts 'echo "trying $host :"; ssh -p 23 myuser@$host "ls -lh /"'

/home/scott/bin/dofor: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token \`3'
/home/scott/bin/dofor: line 14: \`done 3 < $1'`

Comment: Sorry, I lost the essential `exec` somehow :/ Works now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
shift
CMD=$*
cmds=""

source <({
cat $FILE | while read host; do
    echo $CMD | sed -e "s|\$host|$host|g"
done
})
```

Comment: My initial description wasn't very clear

Comment: Does the this version get you what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, that would work, although it's pretty much what I came up w/ also. I was hoping to do something other than replacing values. I was hoping to take advantage of some sort of "scoping" feature of bash

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but it's a *really* bad idea unless you completely control the contents of `$FILE` *and* it only contains very simple statements.

```
while read -r
do
    $REPLY
done < $FILE
```

For the SSH example, you could do something much simpler by just looping over the host names:

```
while read -r host
do
    echo -n "${host}:"
    ssh "$host" hostname
done 9< "$FILE"
```

That should return a list of `my hostname:remote hostname` entries.

If you have a file with actual commands, you have to make sure whitespace is handled properly. The only way to be able to handle *any* parameters (including for example `echo` commands where the parameters are multiple lines) would be to use a custom format. One relatively simple way would be to separate each command and argument with a ␀ character, and put an extra ␀ character between the last argument of a command and the next command.

Comment: I do control contents of that file and it is very basic

Comment: From the example given in the question, I understand that the commands would come from parameters passed to the script, not the file. But I admit the goal is quite unclear.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz correct. I've updated the example in the description